# magic: the gathering enchantment problem

Tags: magic-the-gathering

1. If I have an **enchantment creature** with an *aura* attached to it, and I bestow the **enchantment creature** on another creature, does the *aura* go with it or go to the graveyard?
2. Can an **enchantment creature** be enchanted by another **enchantment creature**?

Comment: When you say "enchantment creature", do you mean a permanent which is both an enchantment and a creature, or do you mean a card (presumably printed before ninth edition) which says "enchant creature" in the type line?

Comment: I mean a permanent that is a creature and an enchantment. I have a deck with a lot of these, so this is important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Bestow can only happen from your hand. While the card is in your hand, it is simultaneously an enchantment card and a creature card. When you cast it as a creature, it becomes an **enchantment creature**. Once the **enchantment creature** is on the battlefield, it is unable to become an "Enchant Creature" spell (I'm reasonably confident that all creatures with Bestow can only enchant creatures). Because of that, the Aura attached to the **enchantment creature** doesn't go anywhere because the **enchantment creature** can't enchant another permanent.
2. Yes. Again, while the card is in your hand, it is simultaneously a creature card and an enchantment card. When you use the Bestow ability, in this instance, the **enchantment creature** being Bestowed becomes an Aura and ceases being a creature; that Aura spell becomes a creature and ceases being an Aura if the creature it is enchanting leaves the battlefield.

Comment: It looks like all of the comments have been addressed so I have cleared them out.

Answer (score 8):

Bestow is a choice that you make while casting a spell. If you choose to cast it with the Bestow cost, it is an Aura spell instead of a Creature spell. This is a choice that you can only make while casting the spell. If the card is already on the battlefield, you can't turn it into an Aura with the Bestow ability.

You can enchant an Enchantment Creature with an Aura that has Enchant Creature, including an Aura that is a bestowed Creature Enchantment card. An Enchantment Creature is just both an Enchantment and a Creature, so it can be affected by things that affect Enchantments, and by things that affect Creatures, including Auras with Enchant Creature. Adding the Enchantment type to a Creature doesn't otherwise do anything special.